# Say hello to GD's new blurb!

Tags: discussion

I would like to introduce you to our new blurb:

> Q&A for Graphic Design professionals, students, and enthusiasts

After some mod discussion we decided to go ahead with this blurb instead of having a vote on the top because there was so much of a vote curve.

[image]

Comment: Well done. Screw democracy this is a theocracy.

Comment: You put in the Oxford comma. That's all I wanted. :)

Comment: Good stuff! @LaurenIpsum i _hate_ that comma... in my language that is a big no-no.

Comment: @RandomO'Reilly I know. Fortunately, there's room for both of us in English. :)

Comment: :-D It should be `Q&A, for Graphic Design professionals, students, and, enthusiasts;`

Comment: I was off last week, but I will work on getting this switched over this week!

Comment: ooops I was late - looks great though!

Comment: It should be question and answer (or Q&A) **site**, because *graphicdesign.stackexchange.com* isn't a question nor an answer itself.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum What is an 'Oxford comma'?

Comment: My apologies I didn't know this was an English Stack  =P

Comment: @poepje It's also known as the serial comma. It's when you use a comma before the conjunction in a series: *Bread, tuna, and mayonnaise* instead of *Bread, tuna and mayonnaise.* People can have strong opinions about it one way or the other.

Comment: @Gramps Nobody ever expects the *English* Inquisition. ;)

Comment: Why is "graphic design" capitalized? It looks kind of strange.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum Ah I see, thanks.